# Android Gradle 1.0 Computing Version code in multi-flavor setup

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

The code to compute version code for different product flavors is no longer working in the Android Gradle 1.0 system.  I used the example code below before successfully.

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/tips#TOC-Computing-Version-code-in-multi-flavor-setup.

productFlavors.get(0).versionCode is now computed as null.

Gradle code..

```
android {

  buildscript {
    repositories {
      mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
  }

  // This actual the app version code. Our given range is [0, 99999]
  defaultConfig.versionCode = 123

  // 2 dimensions of flavors. API is more important than ABI.
  flavorGroups "api", "abi"

  productFlavors {
    gingerbread {
      flavorGroup "api"
      minSdkVersion 10
      versionCode = 1
    }
    icecreamSandwich {
      flavorGroup "api"
      minSdkVersion 14
      // this must be higher than the gingerbread version to ensure update of the
      // app when the device gets a system update from GB to ICS
      versionCode = 2
    }
    x86 {
      flavorGroup "abi"
      ndk.abiFilter "x86"
      // this is the flavor part of the version code.
      // It must be higher than the arm one for devices supporting
      // both, as x86 is preferred.
      versionCode = 3
    }
    arm {
      flavorGroup "abi"
      ndk.abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
      versionCode = 1
    }
    mips {
      flavorGroup "abi"
      // It must be higher than the arm one for devices supporting
      // both, as mips is preferred.
      ndk.abiFilter "mips"
      versionCode = 2
    }
    fat {
      flavorGroup "abi"
      // fat binary, lowest version code to be
      // the last option
      versionCode = 0
    }
  }

  // make per-variant version code
  applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    // get the version code of each flavor
    def apiVersion = variant.productFlavors.get(0).versionCode
    def abiVersion = variant.productFlavors.get(1).versionCode

    // set the composite code
     variant.mergedFlavor.versionCode = apiVersion * 1000000 + abiVersion * 100000 + defaultConfig.versionCode
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [Google user guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors)

> Multi-flavor variants
>
> In some case, one may want to create several versions of the same apps
>   based on more than one criteria. For instance, multi-apk support in
>   Google Play supports 4 different filters. Creating different APKs
>   split on each filter requires being able to use more than one
>   dimension of Product Flavors.
>
> Consider the example of a game that has a demo and a paid version and
>   wants to use the ABI filter in the multi-apk support. With 3 ABIs and
>   two versions of the application, 6 APKs needs to be generated (not
>   counting the variants introduced by the different Build Types).
>   However, the code of the paid version is the same for all three ABIs,
>   so creating simply 6 flavors is not the way to go. Instead, there are
>   two dimensions of flavors, and variants should automatically build all
>   possible combinations.
>
> This feature is implemented using Flavor Dimensions. Flavors are
>   assigned to a specific dimension android {
>       ...
>
> ```
> flavorDimensions "abi", "version"
>
> productFlavors {
>     freeapp {
>         flavorDimension "version"
>         ...
>     }
>
>     x86 {
>         flavorDimension "abi"
>         ...
>     }
> } }
> ```

`flavorGroups` was replaced by `flavorDimensions`, so you need to use next code at `build.gradle`

```
   // 2 dimensions of flavors. API is more important than ABI.
flavorDimensions "api", "abi"

productFlavors {
    gingerbread {
        flavorDimension "api"
        minSdkVersion 10
        versionCode = 1
    }
    icecreamSandwich {
        flavorDimension "api"
        minSdkVersion 14
        // this must be higher than the gingerbread version to ensure update of the
        // app when the device gets a system update from GB to ICS
        versionCode = 2
    }
    x86 {
        flavorDimension "abi"
        ndk.abiFilter "x86"
        // this is the flavor part of the version code.
        // It must be higher than the arm one for devices supporting
        // both, as x86 is preferred.
        versionCode = 3
    }
    arm {
        flavorDimension "abi"
        ndk.abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
        versionCode = 1
    }
    mips {
        flavorDimension "abi"
        // It must be higher than the arm one for devices supporting
        // both, as mips is preferred.
        ndk.abiFilter "mips"
        versionCode = 2
    }
    fat {
        flavorDimension "abi"
        // fat binary, lowest version code to be
        // the last option
        versionCode = 0
    }
}

// make per-variant version code
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    // get the version code of each flavor
    def apiVersion = variant.productFlavors.get(0).versionCode
    def abiVersion = variant.productFlavors.get(1).versionCode

    // set the composite code
    variant.mergedFlavor.versionCode = apiVersion * 1000000 + abiVersion * 100000 + defaultConfig.versionCode
}
```

**Update:**

Add these lines to be able see `versionCode` at generated names of apk

```
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def apk = output.outputFile;
        def newName =  "${output.name}-${variant.mergedFlavor.versionCode}"
        if (variant.buildType.versionNameSuffix) {
            newName += "-${variant.buildType.versionNameSuffix}"
        }
        if (output.zipAlign) {
            output.zipAlign.outputFile = new File((File) apk.parentFile, newName + '-aligned.apk');
        }
        output.packageApplication.outputFile = new File((File) apk.parentFile, newName + ".apk")
    }
}
```

See bellow result of build:

```
    gingerbreadArmDebug-1100123.apk
    gingerbreadArmDebug-1100123-aligned.apk
    gingerbreadFatDebug-1000123.apk
    gingerbreadFatDebug-1000123-aligned.apk
    gingerbreadMipsDebug-1200123.apk
    gingerbreadMipsDebug-1200123-aligned.apk
    gingerbreadX86Debug-1300123.apk
    gingerbreadX86Debug-1300123-aligned.apk
    icecreamSandwichArmDebug-2100123.apk
    icecreamSandwichArmDebug-2100123-aligned.apk
    icecreamSandwichFatDebug-2000123.apk
    icecreamSandwichFatDebug-2000123-aligned.apk
    icecreamSandwichMipsDebug-2200123.apk
    icecreamSandwichMipsDebug-2200123-aligned.apk
    icecreamSandwichX86Debug-2300123.apk
    icecreamSandwichX86Debug-2300123-aligned.apk
    gingerbreadArmRelease-1100123.apk
    gingerbreadFatRelease-1000123.apk
    gingerbreadMipsRelease-1200123.apk
    gingerbreadX86Release-1300123.apk
    icecreamSandwichArmRelease-2100123.apk
    icecreamSandwichFatRelease-2000123.apk
    icecreamSandwichMipsRelease-2200123.apk
    icecreamSandwichX86Release-2300123.apk
```

Info from one of them, extracted by [apktool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/):

```
version: 2.0.0-RC3
apkFileName: gingerbreadArmDebug-1100123.apk
isFrameworkApk: false
usesFramework:
  ids:
  - 1
sdkInfo:
  minSdkVersion: '10'
  targetSdkVersion: '21'
packageInfo:
  forced-package-id: '127'
versionInfo:
  versionCode: '1100123'
  versionName: '1.0'
compressionType: false
```

**Update 2:**

Published my test project at [GitHub](https://github.com/igozhenko/gradle-27508708)

Comment: how do you know which variant you are working with?  Since I want to compute different version codes for each variant.  You're code would compute the same version code for all variants right?

Comment: @TWilly, it's updated your code and looks like it'll compute different `versionCode` for each variant, according its implementation.

Comment: def apiVersion = variant.productFlavors.get(0).versionCode is still computing as null which is my original problem

Comment: @TWilly How do you check `null`? See my update of answer, where I added result of `gradlew clean build` at my side.

Comment: Where are you setting the versioncode?  I'm only seeing you you set the output file name

Comment: Yes, I pushed my test project into [GitHub](https://github.com/igozhenko/gradle-27508708)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67258/discussion-between-gio-and-twilly).