# Android Studio create a build variant / type excluding jniLibs?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android application that uses a native JNI library. I put it into `app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a` without any gradle configuration and Android studio happily bundles it into the APK.

I have a requirement where all native libraries cannot be bundled with a certain distribution. Is it possible to create a build variant or build type that simply excludes all native libraries (maybe even by name `.so`).

The fact that the native library is missing in this distribution doesn't matter because it's not used. The alternative is to physically remove the files, run the build, put them back. However, this is painful and error prone.

Comment: pls post your `build.gradle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your `build.gradle`, we may be able to know what is to be done precisely.

I have used `productFlavours`, combined with `flavorDimensions` to implement builds which may or may not include jni libraries.

From what i understood, gist of it is: `productFlavors` enable you to have n variants of x, y... type, adding `flavorDimensions` would enable you to have n variants of xy type.

Eg. Inside `build.gradle`,

```
    flavorDimensions "abi", "version"  //this is what can help you build with/w/o jni libraries

    productFlavors {
        devel {
            flavorDimension "abi" //keep a dimension common with arm, armv7
            applicationId "com.packagename.dev"
        }
        prod {
       flavorDimension "version"
    // this would be your build w/o the ndk support then
            applicationId "com.packageName"
        }
        armv7 {
            ndk {
                flavorDimension "abi"
                abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
            }
        }
        arm {
            ndk {
                flavorDimension "abi"
                abiFilter "armeabi"
            }
        }

    }
```

As you can see, you will have multiple build variants , product flavors depending on `flavorDimension`.

`prod` flavor would be a build variant or build type that simply excludes all native libraries

Sources for topics ndk, jniLibs, buildFlavours... :
- [Mastering "Product Flavors" on Android](http://blog.brainattica.com/how-to-work-with-flavours-on-android/)
- [ndk-with-android-studio](http://www.shaneenishry.com/blog/2014/08/17/ndk-with-android-studio/)
- [multi flavor setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27508708/android-gradle-1-0-computing-version-code-in-multi-flavor-setup)

Comment: This is a perfect answer (and works). Unfortunately it's just been made clear that we need `libxwalkcore.so` but not `libeposprint.so`. Can I selectively exclude files?

Comment: glad it helped, from what i saw, i don't know how to do that. Doesn't seem likely if it can be done, hope there's a way though!

Comment: @user2450263 - Is it possible to swap jniLibs resources based on build flavors? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31687547/gradle-swap-jnilibs-resources-based-on-build-flavor.. Much appreciated!!