# Gradle swap jniLibs resources based on build flavor

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to swap some resources in the `res/raw` folder and the `jniLibs/armeabi` folder based on whether its a `release buildType` or a `debug buildType`. I currently have two product flavors as well.

The build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    productFlavors{
        phone{
            applicationId "com.example.testPhone"
        }
        tablet{
            applicationId "com.example.testTablet"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    sourceSets{
        release{
            res.srcDirs = ['androidRelease/res/raw']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':facebook')

}
```

Is using `sourceSet` the right way to do so? If it is, what folder should be created so that it swaps the appropriate resources based on the `buildType` only and irrespective of the `productFlavors`?

EDIT: Is it even possible to swap `jniLibs` and `raw` folder resources?

Folder Structure:

```
src/main/jniLibs/armeabi
phoneRelease/jniLibs/armeabi
tabletRelease/jniLibs/armeabi
```

Is the folder structure correct.?

EDIT 2:
Based on Xavier's answer should the gradle look like this:

```
android {

      sourcesets {
        phone {
          jniLibs.srcDirs = ['phoneRelease/jniLibs/']
          res.srcDirs = ['androidRelease/res/raw']
        }
        tablet {
          jniLibs.srcDirs = ['tabletRelease/jniLibs/']
          res.srcDirs = ['androidRelease/res/raw']
        }
      }
    }
```

I keep reading lot of conflicting answers, some of them mention that you just need separate folders based on build variant and some mention about having to use `sourceSet`? 
Thanks!

Comment: My understanding is that you don't use build types for this, but rather flavors. I see you are looking for a 2D solution however.

Comment: How about i go about using flavors? can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> some of them mention that you just need separate folders based on build variant and some mention about having to use sourceSet?

Gradle/Gradle for Android has an expected structure for a sourceset:

- Android resources in `res/`
- Java source tree in `java/`
- Pre-compiled JNI libraries in `jniLibs/`
- Assets in `assets/`
- Etc.

Where the `sourceSets` closure comes into play is if, for a given sourceset, you want a *different structure*:

- Android resources in `foo/`
- Java source tree in `bar/`
- Pre-compiled JNI libraries in `ickyNativeStuff/`
- Assets in `assetsBecauseThatSeemsLikeADecentName/`
- Etc.

Each build type, product flavor, and build variant can have a separate sourceset (as can `androidTest` for instrumentation testing), to go along with `main`. They are named the same as the build type/product flavor/build variant. These will be in the stock structure, unless you use `sourceSets` to change things.

So, to roll all the way back to:

> I am trying to swap some resources in the res/raw folder and the jniLibs/armeabi folder based on whether its a release buildType or a debug buildType

In the case of resources, other sourcesets overlay `main`. So, if you have `src/main/res/...` and `src/main/debug/...` and `src/main/release/...`, and you are doing a `debug` build, whatever is in `src/main/release/...` is ignored (as we aren't doing `release`) and whatever is in `src/main/res/...` and `src/main/debug/...` will be used. If there is the same resource in both (`src/main/res/raw/boom.ogg` and `src/debug/res/raw/boom.ogg`), the `debug` one trumps the `main` one.

I have not experimented with varying `jniLibs/` by build variant. My guess is that it will behave more like Java code, where you cannot have conflicts between what is in a build variant's sourceset and what is in `main`, but that's just a guess. So, you can have the debug version of your compiled JNI code in `src/debug/jniLibs/` and the release version of your compiled JNI code in `src/release/jniLibs/`. Only have in `src/main/jniLibs/` any libraries that are not varying. That being said, as I mentioned, I haven't tried this, and so there may be hiccups here.

So, I would expect you to not have a `sourcesets` closure in `build.gradle`, and to just use the stock sourcesets structure, for your various bits:

```
src/
  main/
    ...
  debug/
    jniLibs/
    res/
      raw/
  release
    jniLibs/
    res/
      raw/
```

Comment: Apologies for the way too much delayed response. This did work. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Anything that's normally under `src/main/` can be put in a different folder:

```
src/<element>/AndroidManifest.xml
src/<element>/java
src/<element>/res
src/<element>/assets
src/<element>/resources
src/<element>/jni
src/<element>/jniLibs
src/<element>/aidl
src/<element>/rs
```

Where `element` is the name of a `build type` or a `product flavor`. If your variant includes such a element (build type or flavor), then that source set is also used **in addition** to `src/main`

Note that the location is really not relevant if you have configured it.
What matters is that there is a `android.sourcesets.main` element that contains the sources common to all variants, and each variant has a set of sourcesets.

For instance if you have a flavor `phoneRelease` it's really using the following sourcesets:

```
android.sourcesets.main
android.sourcesets.phone
android.sourcesets.release
android.sourcesets.phoneRelease
```

If you have another variant `tabletRelease`, it'll use the following:

```
android.sourcesets.main
android.sourcesets.tablet
android.sourcesets.release
android.sourcesets.phoneRelease
```

So the `phone`/`tablet` sourceset is different and is where you'd put the variant specific sources, unless you want to be even more specific and use the `phoneRelease`/`tabletRelease` sourcesets (though those are less used generally.) By default these would be `src/phone/...` and `src/tablet/...` (or `src/phoneRelease/...`) but you can change that however you want and as long as it's connected to the `android.sourcesets.*` objects it'll be fine.

for example, doing:

```
android {
  sourcesets {
    phone {
      jniLibs.srcDirs = ['phoneRelease/jniLibs/']
    }
    tablet {
      jniLibs.srcDirs = ['tabletRelease/jniLibs/']
    }
  }
}
```

is fine. But do be aware that you only changed the jniLibs folder and not the other source elements (java, res, etc...)

If you kept the default location for the `main` sourcesets, I'd just keep everything under `src/`

You can see more info about sourcesets and how multiple sourcesets are combined here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Sourcesets-and-Dependencies

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quick..!! I do have separate folder already created for different productFlavors. But for some reason it seems to be picking up the wrong one. I shall edit my question here to highlight that. I am specificlally trying to swap out a .so file from jniLibs/armeabi based on productFlavors

Comment: The actual location of the folders doesn't matter. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. I am utterly confused now. I have edited my question. Simply put i want to swap out jniLibs and raw folder for release builds. What needs to be done? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

To use flavors to vary source sets,

```
productFlavors{
    phone{
    }
    tablet{
    }
}
```

Now structure your code like,

```
src
  main
  phone
  tablet
```

The code in `main` is common between both flavors, but the code in `phone` or `tablet` is only included when the respective flavor is built. That's it, you don't need to do anything else.

The structure under `phone` and `tablet` is the same as under `main` (`res`, `java`, etc). You can also have a custom `AndroidManifest.xml` under the flavor directory. Gradle attempts to merge the flavor's `AndroidManifest.xml` with the one in main. In some cases you have to provide rules for how to merge.

Comment: how does the structure above differentiate between debug and release build types? I only want to swap resources based on release or debug

Comment: As I said above, you use flavors for this, not build types. You then asked this: "How about i go about using flavors?" of which I answered above.

Comment: but wouldnt this only work for product flavors? example how to make it work for phoneRelease only