# Build a Bundle App for Google play 64bits and 32 bits

Tags: android

I'm here with this problem that have me crazy already.

We were uploading APKs with no problem to the store. Suddenly google play changed their rules and now you only can upload APKs with only 64 bits. So we find out which module of our app has 32 bits folders and deleted them. We generated an APK and uploaded it. No problem, no errors, no warnings. BUT now we have a lot of devices that can not download the app, of course. The old ones, and we need them.

So I tried to generate a Bundle to upload, and I did it. But I am having the SAME problem. Here is what I did:
I have an AAR included in the project that was the one with the 32/64 bits problem. So we opened the project of the AAR and deleted the 32 bits folders, generated the AAR again and included again in the project.

Then I generated the BUNDLE and uploaded to the store. No errors, no warnings, no nothing. But the problem that we had before with the apk is still here, old phones can not download the app.
So then I restored the OLD AAR, with re 32 bits folders, and I generated a BUNDLE with this things in Gradle app file:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ar.com.redlink.vale"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 80
    versionName "3.15.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86'
    dimension "default"
}
splits {
    abi {
        include  'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86'
    }
}
```

I tried to upload the Bundle to the store and I get the error that mi files have 32 bits things, so I can not upload it.

I don't know what else to do. Maybe I am not understanding this thing right.

Comment: Not sure if I would call the 64-bit requirement [sudden](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html) but you don't mention what 32-bit libraries you are using OR if you tried to [productFlavors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30995947/295004)?

Comment: We have a Biometry library that we tuned and made the AAR file and included it on the project. That library had 32bits folders, that the support people of the library said to us to delete them.

Comment: Possibly related: [APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices but they only have 32-bit native code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57561855/295004) as I noticed you have 'x86' but not 'x86_64'